# In OCaml, why is the list constructor :: not an operator

Tags: list, constructor, ocaml

I was reading today Jason Hickey's online book "Introduction to Objective Caml" and in the chapter on Functors (page 140) I ran into the following line inside the Set functor's definition:

```
let add = (::)
```

Running the code resulted in a not very illuminating 'Syntax error' error message. After plugin in the line into ocaml toplevel I figured out that `::` is in fact not an operator, but rather a type constructor.

However, from what little I know of Haskell the equivalent `:` constructor can be treated as an operator (function) as well.

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

My question is: have OCaml constructors never been first class values (implying that the code from the book was wrong from the start) and why is this the case?

Comment: I normally use `(fun x y -> x :: y)` to overcome this issue (converts the operator to a lambda). It's a bit annoying but works. Also, even if `::` was a function, you'd still have to do the same whenever you need the arguments for `::` swapped, so I guess it makes some sense in that respect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Caml Light, OCaml's predecessor, it used to be the case that constructors where promoted to functions when partially applied. I'm not exactly sure why this feature was removed when moving to OCaml, and I lament this as well, but the explanation I heard was "nobody used that". So no `List.map Some foo` anymore...

`::` is slightly special as an algebraic datatype constructor as it is the only infix constructor (hardcoded in the parser), but otherwise behaves like any other datatype constructor.

Comment: I do not remember hearing "nobody used that" explanation. I think the motivation was to stress the difference between functions and constructors...

Comment: That's interesting to hear. I'm concurrently reading the "Functional approach to programming" using Caml Light and have on several ocassions found the language nicer than OCaml (default pattern matching for fun definition, let-in-where form and inbuilt function composition operator).

Comment: Xavier answered more than 10 years ago: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2001/08/47db53a4b42529708647c9e81183598b.fr.html

Comment: @camlspotter Nice find! And to correct my previous comment, the book "Functional approach to programming" uses CAML and not Caml Light as I falsely stated.

Comment: unfortunately, 10 more years and that link doesn't work.

Comment: the link has the year and month, so it's not too hard to find the message again: https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/caml-list/2001-08/msg00022.html